# how to change a value of specific object in an array of objects in mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, patch

i have a schema that contains an object with type array , i want to make an api to change specific field in that array maybe change its name or delete it

```
const customerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    description: String,
    fields: {
       type: [{
        name: String,
        environment: String,
        challenges: String,
        solution: String
    }],
    default: []
}
});
```

how to make a patch or delete requests on an object of fields array

Answer (score 1):

i figured out i can use nested documents if anyone faced that problem